# How to set UICollectionView datasource in UITableView when having two different type of UITableViewCell in one TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm learning `UICollectionView` and applying it to my ios app. However, I got a problem that I cannot reload data of `UICollectionView`.

P.S. the data has already been stored in an array called `queriedGroups` successfully. I only have two section in `UITableView`.

**TableViewCell:**

I defined a `UICollectionview` in a `UITableViewCell` and a method which set up the `delegate` and `datasource` for `UICollectionView`. Here is the method:

```
- (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.indexPath = indexPath;

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

**TableViewController:**

In `UITableView`, I have two different type of `TableViewCell`: 1) the one that contains the `UICollectionView`; 2) a typical `UITableViewCell`.

Here is how I set up these two `TableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

        GroupCategoryViewCell *cell = (GroupCategoryViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[GroupCategoryViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        return cell;
    } else {
        static NSString *GroupCellIdentifier = @"GroupListViewCell";
        if (indexPath.row < queriedGroups.count) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:GroupCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:GroupCellIdentifier];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = queriedGroups[indexPath.row];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

            return cell;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And here is the `willDisplayCell:`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(GroupCategoryViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self indexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I have applied `UICollectionView` successfully in a `UITableView` with just only one type of `UITableViewCell` at another controller. In that controller, `willDisplayCell:` method can successfully set up the `delegate` and `datasource` for `UICollectionView`.

However, it obviously cannot work for the controller that has two different type of `UITableViewCell` in one `UITableView`.

**How can I set up the `delegate` and `datasource` for `UICollectionView` and reload data in this situation?**

Thank you so much for helping me solve my problem. I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Does willDisplayCell is called ??

Comment: I don't think so.